# Android Studio: Push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am creating an app where a user adds food to a fridge. When they add the food they enter the name, type and best before date.

I want to show a push notification when the food is going to expire in one day. If the food is expired it should be deleted from the fridge and firebase database.

Here is what I have so far:

The check if expired method:

```
//notification
private void checkIfExpiring()
{
Date todayDate = new Date();
Date expiryDate = new Date();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();



Log.e("AddFood","Calendar is: " + cal);


for (Food item: foods){
    try {
        expiryDate = new Date(item.getBestBefore());
        cal.setTime(expiryDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR,24);
        Log.e("AddFood","Try catch Expiry is: " + expiryDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        expiryDate = new Date();
    }
    if (expiryDate.before(todayDate)){
        Log.e("AddFood","before today Expiry is: " + expiryDate);
        scanned_Food = item;
        //remove from db
    }
   if(cal.after(todayDate)){
        Log.e("AddFood","After today Expiry is: " + expiryDate);
        showNotification();
    }

}
```

The notification:

```
//push notification
    private void showNotification(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"bestBeforeNotification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Warning")
            .setContentText("Going off")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, builder.build());
```

}

I call the method in the onStart() method:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                result = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("barcode_result");
                barcode_Result.setText(result);
                if (checkIfExists(result)) {
                    Log.w("addFood","It Exists");
                    editTextName.setText(scanned_Food.getFoodName());
                    //spinnerCategory.setText(scanned_Food.getFoodCategory());
                    barcode_Result.setText(scanned_Food.getBarcode());
                    dateText.setText(scanned_Food.getBestBefore());
                }
            }
        checkIfExpiring();
    }
```

For the best before date the user uses a date picker:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(),year, month, day);
```

}

and here is where I set the text:

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, i);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, i1);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i2);
        String currentDateString = c.getTime().toString();

//        TextView dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DateText);
        dateText.setText(currentDateString);
    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
Calendar is: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1520174879158,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Dublin,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=9,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_YEAR=63,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=47,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=158,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]

Try catch Expiry is: Sun Mar 04 20:19:04 GMT+00:00 2018
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: I want to show a push notification when the food is going to expire in one day. If the food is expired it should be deleted from the fridge and firebase database.

At the moment no push notification shows even when I have something in the database with an expiry date that is within one day